# Undefined property session in cp_js_end hook

Tags: add-on-development, sessions, hook, development

Currently facing the following error in the `cp_js_end` hook.

```
Undefined property: Javascript::$session
```

it looks like the session class isn`t loading anymore in EE 2.6+ It whas working in older versions.

Is this a bug, or did EL change the way of loading the session class in some other order?

Example:

```
function cp_js_end()
{
   print_r(ee()->session);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code part of extension which is causing this error.

Comment: Example added to the item.

Comment: for more info about this 'bug', see https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19469

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way to avoid this problem

I change the hook from `cp_js_end` to the `cp_menu_array` hook.

```
Will work
function cp_menu_array($menu)
{
    print_r(ee()->session)
}
```

Please make sure that you not returning your JS but add your js with to the with `ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript"></script>');`